# tqdm: How to check the completion of a code

Tags: python

I'm working now a code in NLP that can take up to an hour to run, and I want a tool that shows me the completion of this code, like when you install a file for example and there's a progression bar in pourcentage. I want the same thing for my code. I think we can do that with tqdm but I don't know how because I've never used tqdm like that before so if someone knows thx in advance

Comment: [TQDM documentation](https://tqdm.github.io/) is quite good, you could try looking into it.

Comment: the problem is that it doesn't give me a way to connect a tqdm loop with my code. What the documentation says is that you can display a progression AFTER the code is compiled which is not what I want

Comment: So you should display a snippet of your code here, without it is pretty hard to suggest anything.